# Selecting default implementation from indirectly inherited Interface not working

Tags: java, interface, diamond-problem, default-method

I have 4 Classes that look like this:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
...
default boolean isEmpty() {
    return false; //dummy value real implementation is not relevant for the problem
}
}

public interface CharSequence { //java.lang.CharSequence
...
default boolean isEmpty() {
    return true; //dummy value real implementation is not relevant for the problem
}

public abstract class Bar<T> implements Foo<T> {
...
}

public final BarImpl extends Bar<Character> implements CharSequence { //typical diamond problem
...
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() { //needed to resolve diamond problem
   return Foo.super.isEmpty() // Compile Error: No enclosing instance of the type Foo<T> is accessible in scope
   return Bar.super.isEmpty() // Compile Error: No enclosing instance of the type Bar<T> is accessible in scope
   return CharSequence.super.isEmpty() // compiles
}
```

Why can't I access the default implementation coming from extending Bar?

Comment: that's invalid syntax in java, static classes are c# features.

Comment: `Bar` doesn't have an implementation, nor override, thus you can't reference that. `super.isEmpty` does work and defaults to `Foo::isEmpty`. If you implement `isEmpty` in bar, `super.isEmpty` will point to `Bar::isEmpty`.

Comment: That seems to work. Sonar lint is informing me that the overriding of isEmpty is redundant (Remove this method to simply inherit it) but it seems to be a wrong info, since not inherenting produces the (expected) hard diamond error. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please write an answer, that I can close the question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BarImpl` can not invoke `Foo`’s `default` method explicitly, as `BarImpl` is not directly implementing `Foo`. It’s extending `Bar` which directly implements `Foo`, hence, it’s `Bar`’s decision to override `Foo`’s `default` method or not.

`BarImpl` can only invoke `Bar`’s `isEmpty()` method via `super.isEmpty()`, which may end up at `Foo`’s `default` method if `Bar` decides not to override it or at a concrete method of `Bar` if it does override it.

Note that `T.super.method()` can only be used if either, `T` is a directly implemented super interface (i.e. not already implemented by a super class or another super interface) or if `T` is an enclosing type of an inner class. The second use case is the reason for the “*No enclosing instance of … is accessible in scope*” error message.

```java
import java.util.Objects;

class Test {
  public static void main(String... arg) {
    System.out.println(new BarImpl().isEmpty());
  }
}

public interface Foo<T> {
  default boolean isEmpty() {
      System.out.println("  Foo's default method");
      return false;
  }
}

public abstract class Bar<T> implements Foo<T> {
}

public final class BarImpl extends Bar<Character> implements CharSequence {
  @Override
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    System.out.println("calling (Bar) super.isEmpty();");
    super.isEmpty();
    System.out.println("calling CharSequence.super.isEmpty();");
    return CharSequence.super.isEmpty();
  }

  public char charAt(int index) {
    Objects.checkIndex(index, length());
    return (char)('A' + index);
  }

  public int length() {
    System.out.println("  length() [CharSequence's default method]");
    return 26;
  }

  public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
    Objects.checkFromToIndex(start, end, length());
    return new StringBuilder(end - start).append(this, start, end);
  }

  public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder(length()).append(this, 0, length()).toString();
  }
}
```

```
calling (Bar) super.isEmpty();
  Foo's default method
calling CharSequence.super.isEmpty();
  length() [CharSequence's default method]
false
```